# When to Use Virtual Objects in QTP?

Tags: qtp

When to Use Virtual Objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use them only if all other approaches failed.
Virtual Objects are based on relative coordinates, the properties that are quite unstable. That is maintanance cost is high.
I even prefer using keyboard navigation to Virtual objects.

Comment: could you give an example for virtual object usage, my purpose for learning how to use virtual objects, i read in help but i didn't understood that one. please provide one suitable example for virtual object

Comment: The example used in the QTP training class is the color palette in Paint.exe. The color palette is a single object, but in a test you would want to click individual colors as if they are discrete buttons. However, I agree with katmoon@ that you should only use virtual objects as a last resort. In fact, I have never used them on a real project.